# Can't resize partitions

Tags: boot, gparted, resize

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows and I trying to make a Linux partition bigger, but I can't.

[image: screenshot of GParted, showing list of partitions]

[image: screenshot of GParted, showing resize window]

Comment: The little key icons show that your system is mounted. You need to use the Ubuntu live installer with gparted or a gparted live ISO. And make sure all partitions are unmounted. Then you can move partition left & expand right.Another alternative is to use space as /home. And then move all data in existing /home that is inside / to new partition.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 2):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda5 full left
- **resize** the right side of sda5 all the way to the right*

  - unless you wish to leave some space for a swap partition
- click the Apply icon